# ¿Cómo puedo cerrar un Forms y abrir otro y que no sea escondiendolo?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He tratado con este código, pero queda activa la aplicación y no he encontrado mucha información con el tema.

```
Frm_Inicio frm = new Frm_Inicio();
frm.Show();
this.Hide();
```

Comment: con el .dispose(), quiza eso es lo que buscas.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo puedo integrar?

Comment: Llama al form principal desde el segundo form, asi cuando abras el segundo le pones que cierre el otro formulario

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no queda claro que queres hacer...

Answer (score -2):

Usa el método [Close()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.close?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) que se útiliza especificamente para cerrar el formulario y todos sus recursos creados,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si quieres únicamente "esconder" el Formulario puedes llamar el método [Hide()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.hide?view=windowsdesktop-8.0#system-windows-window-hide)

Comment: Creo que lo que haces no soluciona el problema del op, que pasaría si el formulario que cierras es el principal de la aplicación? Se mostraría un segundo formulario o la aplicación se cerraría completa?